# Web crawling <!--suppress HtmlUnknownAttribute -->

Tags: python, html, web-crawler

I was trying to crawl the link : "http://codeforces.com/contest/554/standings" .

I used the given two lines to read all contestant names :

```
table1 = soup.find("table", {'class':'standings'})
table2 = table1.find_all("tr")
```

However table2 doesn't print all the table rows.
I found " <--suppress HtmlUnknownAttribute --> " written before all the rows I wasn't able to crawl.

Is there any particular reason for it.

I am just a beginner to web crawling

Comment: What do you get printed: `print(len(table2))`?

Comment: `<!--suppress HtmlUnknownAttribute -->` is a HTML comment, it should not affect your parsing.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to share the code in entirety. I get the expected 100 contestant names based on your initial "tr" `find_all`:

```
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

response = urllib2.urlopen('http://codeforces.com/contest/554/standings')
html = response.read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

table = soup.find('table', {'class': 'standings'})
rows = table.find_all('tr')

for row in rows:
    contestant = row.find_all('td', {'class': 'contestant-cell'})
    if len(contestant) > 0:
        # Quick'n dirty dig. Makes un-safe assumptions about the HTML structure.
        print contestant[0].a.string
```

You'll note that some additional digging is required after you get the table rows since not every row contains contestant info.